# Is there a way to select a value from a field with a regexp value?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have some tables with records loaded with regular expressions as values.

Example:

table1

```
record1 - field1, field2, field3 = ^19[8-9][0-9]$    
record2 - field1, field2, field3 = ^20[0-1][0-9]$
```

I would like to select in the following way:

```
select field1, field2 from table where field3 = '1980';
```

**record1** must be selected with the current values:

```
field1, field2
```

I am not finding the `REGEXP` function/parameter which I can do that.

Comment: Are you using `WHERE field3 RLIKE ?`

Comment: Yes I but it is not returning any result. I think RLIKE only works with the regexp itself  but not with the absolute values.  Also I was looking for a way to select using a regexp to select another regexp but I was not successful.

Comment: You're showing a regular expression in your first example, but not in your second. Can you show the query you're actually running?

Comment: If these are numerical values, why not `field3 BETWEEN 1980 AND 1999`?

Comment: The select is basically from the first example.   The field3 value can be for example: ^346$|^868$|^869$|^28776$

Comment: The BETWEEN did not work because the field3 value is a regexp: ^346$|^868$|^869$|^28776$

Comment: Also I tried : select field1, field2 from table where field3 = '^1980$';   but it did not match !  Because the field3 may be it is considered a full text string not a regexp.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. But you might need `WHERE '1980' RLIKE field3`.

Comment: Does ur reqt got fulfilled ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to deal with this. One is to use `IN` for matching any in a list:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE field3 IN (346, 868, 869, 28776)
```

Or for ranges use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE field3 BETWEEN 1980 AND 1999
```

It's only in cases of actual arbitrary string matching you'll want to use regular expressions, for example:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE field3 RLIKE '^XYZ-\d+$'
```

Comment: But in fact I need to match records with a   field3 value such as ^19[8-9][0-1]$  so I can select field1, field2  from table1 where field3 (someway) = '1985';

Comment: I'm not sure why that regular expression is necessary. Does the field contain, *literally*, `^19[8-9][0-1]$`? Are you trying to select in a numerical range?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you will need.

**Query:**
`WITH data
     AS (SELECT 'Data for Row 1 Column 1' field1, 'Some random text' field2, '^19[8-9][0-9]$' REG FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'Data for Row 2 Column 1' field1, 'Another random text' field2, '^20[0-1][0-9]$' REG FROM DUAL)
SELECT field1, field2
FROM DATA
WHERE REGEXP_COUNT('1999',REG) = 1;`

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @Fabio Cardoso  
Did you try any of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could juste [the `REGEXP` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to check the input parameter against each regexp stored in column `field3`. `REGEXP` (which can also be spelled `RLIKE`) is available since early versions of MySQL (5.5) :

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE '1980' REGEXP field3
```

From the documentation :

> `expr REGEXP pat` : Returns `1` if the string `expr` matches the regular expression specified by the pattern `pat`, `0` otherwise. If either `expr` or `pat` is `NULL`, the return value is `NULL`.

Starting with MySQL 8.0, `REGEXP_LIKE()` can also be used :

```
SELECT t1, t2 FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('1980', field3);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/74KdD4Ped6YpYMQz7iMgBk/1)** :

```
with t as (
  select  1 field1, 1 field2, '^19[8-9][0-9]$' field3
  UNION ALL select 2, 2, '^20[0-1][0-9]$'
)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE '1980' REGEXP field3;

| field1 | field2 | field3         |
| ------ | ------ | -------------- |
| 1      | 1      | ^19[8-9][0-9]$ |
```